# Qt multiple mouse clicks at the same time

Tags: c++, qt, multi-touch

I have an application that has two buttons, and I want to detect when both buttons are pressed at the same time.

I have installed another mouse on my Ubuntu 10.04 computer and enabled the second pointer following these steps: http://ao2.it/en/blog/2010/01/19/poor-mans-multi-touch-using-multiple-mice-xorg
I've executed the example there (demo-paint) and I can perform simultaneous independent drawings with each mouse.

But on my Qt application, if I keep Button1 pressed with mouse1 and move mouse2 and press button2, button1 is immediately unpressed, so I can't keep both pressed at the same time.

Is there anyway to allow both buttons to keep pressed at the same time?

Comment: Out of curiosity, might I ask why? What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm using necessitas (http://sourceforge.net/p/necessitas/home/necessitas/) to deploy this application in Android, the issue I've introduced is just a dummy example, the goal is to have multi touch in an Android application. But I have the same issue on the Android device that on the desktop computer.

Comment: I don't know about Qt on Android, but Qt itself has multi-touch support through QTouchEvent. Perhaps that's something to look at?

Comment: I believe that's just what I was looking for. I've installed the fingerpaint example in my device and it works like a charm. Maybe you want to reformulate this as an answer so other people can see it, or I'll answer myself it when I've found a working solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unaware of Qt on the Android platform, but for our tablet and touchscreen applications we handle multi-touch events via Qt's [QTouchEvent](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qtouchevent.html). I would assume something similar should be (or perhaps is already) available for the Qt's Android support.